# How can I wire up commands when a control is dragged from the toolbox (WPF)

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm developing a user control.  My control should be visible whenever the user presses ALT + S anywhere in the active Window.  I'm going to use an ICommand and input bindings to achieve this.

My question is: how can I wire this code up when a developer drags my control from the toolbox to their Window design surface?  I know the code I want to generate (Window.CommandBindings etc) but don't know how to make that happen from the toolbox.

Is there a way to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee712573.aspx) might be useful.